# “Быть” with tenses, gender, number but in affirmative sentences

Tags: грамматика, узус, tense, синтаксис

A homework question, exactly quoted,

```
В этот период у нас было много неожиданных трудностей.
```

but in reviewing my previous question, [When to use 'не было' and 'не будет' regardless of person, gender, or number](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/13964/when-to-use-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE-and-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82-regardless-of-person-gender-or-number) I am reassured that, without negation, the verb `быть` needs to agree in gender and number with the noun.

The last word, the noun, is feminine, but plural.

- I believe that without `много`, the trailing adjective and noun would be nominative plural.

  Correct?

  I often think of verbs, prepositions, etc. affecting other words 'downstream', and yet it seems `много` affects the verb `быть`.

  Is this a fair assessment?
- So should the sentence actually use `были`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Indeed **были** can be used *without* **много**, which ultimately changes the meaning of the sentence

> В этот период у нас были неожиданные трудности. *(no info on their volume)*

2. No. In the original sentence the subject is not **неожиданные трудности** but **много *(неожиданных трудностей)***, and naturally the predicate **быть** conforms to the properties of the subject. It's only natural for a subject to affect a predicate.

Subject can be either noun, pronoun, numeral or null. Here we have it as a numerical pronoun.

Comment: As много is an adverb (genderless), how does it match the neutral/neuter from of быть, as here было?

Comment: @nate **много** here isn't an adverb but a numeric pronoun and words of this class always assume neuter gender, **много** would be an adverb in a sentence such as **я выпил много вина** (HOW MUCH wine?) but a subject in a sentence **много вина было выпито мной** (WHAT was drunk?)

Comment: Seems I need a more complete source than: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE Thank you - that is very helpful!

Comment: @nate, if you're a fluent Russian reader please take a look at [this article](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/41-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_russkii_yazyk_i_kultura_obscheniya/stages/783-33_nekotorye_osobennosti_soglasovaniya.html) which describes principles of agreement between subject and predicate (bar paragraph 2.)

Comment: Thanks for the link! (not fluent but will be) :)

Comment: When **много** governs a countable noun, the predicate *can* be plural: "Много людей покинул**и** институт." http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EC%ED%EE%E3%EE%20%EB%FE%E4%E5%E9&p=1&docid=114388

Comment: @Sergey Slepov you're right, but not always, for example in a phrase **много людей было напугано**, **были напуганы** isn't totally incorrect but to my ear still sounds a bit off

Comment: Yes, that's why I italicised *can* in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

In case there is an adverb describing quality (много, несколько, немного etc.) or a numerical, the verb быть must be in neutral singular, i. e. `в автобусе было двадцать человек`, `у нас было несколько домов`, `в зоопарке было много животных`.  Same with сколько:

> - Сколько котов было у вас?
> - У меня было пять котов.

Comment: "Несколько ступенек стал**и** продолжением садовой дорожки." http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%ED%E5%F1%EA%EE%EB%FC%EA%EE&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=2&lex2=&gramm2=V%2Cpraet%2Cpl&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&p=2&docid=113680

Comment: Никакого отношения к тому, что я написал.